# What is the right option for this sentence?

Tags: prepositions

The following multiple choice question is from a competitive exam.

> Q: You are **fortunate** `________`  having an intelligent and obedient son.
>
> a) For
>   b) Of
>   c) In
>   d) To

I opted *for* as the correct option, but they say the answer is *in*.

What is the correct option, and why is (only?) that one correct?

Comment: Hi Sandeep, welcome to ELL! Can you tell us which answer you think it might be (or one you think it might *not* be) and why? We can give you the answer, of course, but it would help us with our thought-process in explaining if we knew what you were thinking about the question.

Comment: This question is from a competetive exam. I opted 'for'. In the key, they mentioned the answer as 'in'. So, thought of checking with you.

Comment: [Welcome to ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/about)! I was so free as to edit your comment into your original post (although that will not be visible before being reviewed) and just wanted to point out that it is still possible for you to improve your post by editing after you asked it.

Comment: In most contexts(normal conversation rather than a test) I would most likely pause (a comma) after "fortunate" without any other addition or
You are fortunate to have an intelligent and obedient son.

Answer (score 7):

This is one of those easy-to-answer hard-to-explain questions.

Let's examine them all to see what works and what doesn't.

> You are fortunate **for** having an intelligent and obedient son.

Fortunate is an adjective. We are saying that you are fortunate, and then explaining what is causing you to be fortunate. When explaining causation, *for* can be a suitable choice.

> He lives happy **for** all is well.

---

> You are fortunate **of** having an intelligent and obedient son.

You cannot use *of* this way with fortunate. Of is a word that explains a cause, origin, direction, or feature of something.

> He is *of* noble birth.
>
> She is living west *of* here.
>
> I am drinking a cup *of* juice.

You can never say: He is **of having**. It is not a sensible construction.

---

> You are fortunate **in** having an intelligent and obedient son.

You can make a case for in here. In is a word that implies you're including something.

> I was **in** the red until I got my finances in order.
>
> She was **in** trouble for something she did not do.

While it is not the ideal answer, you can easily make a case for it.

---

> You are fortunate **to** having an intelligent and obedient son.

To implies an action or a direction.

> I am walking **to** the liquor store.
>
> I am trying **to** get drunk.
>
> I am going **to** regret my actions.

We generally do not say **to having**. You can say **have to** as in

> I **have to** pee.

The best of the four seems to be **for**. You are lucky **for** your health. You are happy **for** your success.

Comment: +1. Regarding *to*, I would also add that the most common way to say the sentence in question would likely be *You are fortunate* ***to have*** *an intelligent and obedient son*. (Note the use of *have*, not *having*).

Comment: Agreed. I never like these types of exercises since the sentences aren't usually formed as well as they might be, and a case can sometimes be made for more than one answer.

Comment: This is a great answer for the most part, although a quick look at this NGram shows that actually "you are fortunate in" is, in fact, more idiomatic than "you are fortunate for": http://books.google.com/ngrams/chart?content=you+are+fortunate+in%2C+you+are+fortunate+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=